# android install custom ttf font from url

Tags: android, truetype

What I need is to install a custom font to my application on Android, but the problem is that my ttf file come from the server, and as I know that assets folder is read only so we cannot add the downloaded ttf file programmatically.

Is there a way to install the custom font programmatically on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download it to the file system then use `Typeface.createFromFile` to get a Typeface object for it.